# Perform an addition with form fields. without leaving page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I want to perform some maths with some form fields, (basically calculate something ;) )

I have three fields, and want to add them together, whilst multiplying them by a fixed number.

Currently I am doing this with PHP, and it works fine, but I have modified the website design to be all HTML5 and CSS3, and think that it would be great if the user could enter the details into the form and then see the result instantly.

What's the best way to do this?

Have you any example code or tutorials?

Comment: javascript is the way, but for us to help you better, maybe you can show the kind of calculation you want to do

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely something for javascript ;) Due to the ease of use, I will describe it using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#calculate").click(function(e) {
      var value1 = $("#value1").val();
      var value2 = $("#value2").val();
      var value3 = $("#value3").val();

      var result = (value1 + value2 + value3) * 5;
      $("#result").val(result);
      e.preventDefault();
   };
}
```

This assumes, you have 4 input fields. The first three ones have the ids `value1`, `value2` and `value3` and the last one has the id `result`, where the result will be written. Furthermore, you include a button with id `calculate`, which when clicked, will trigger the calculation.

Comment: The how would I display the result?

Comment: It's in the line before `e.preventDefault()`. The call to `$("#result").val(...)` sets the inputs value to the calculation result. I will edit it... one sec.

Answer (score 0):

EIther JavaScript or Ajax can solve your problem. These can do your job dynamically.

Comment: It would be fairly absurd to use AJAX when Javascript has a great mathematical library

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com) installed you can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("input").keyup(function ()
    {
        field_one = $("input[name='some_field']").val();
        field_two = $("input[name='some_field_2']").val();
        field_three = $("input[name='some_field_3']").val();

        result = field_one+field_two+field_three;

        /* any other calculations */

        $("input[name='result_input']").val(result);
    });
});
</script>
```

You don't need jQuery but it's fairly helpful at simplifying this sort of thing. Replace $("input") with a selector that is specific to the inputs you are using to calculate the result.

Comment: This won't work, the script is executed once upon page load but not when any values are entered.

Answer (score 0):

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('toAdd');

var myLength = elems.length,
total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
  total += elems[i].value;
}

document.getElementById('total').value = total;